# How to put(String, List<MyObject>) into a Map<String, List<Object>>

Tags: java, list, dictionary, casting

I have a map of `<String, Lists>`, but the entries have lists of different types.

So the first entry might be `put("cars", List<Cars>)`, and the second entry might be `put("bikes", List<Bikes>)`.

I declared a `Map<String, List<Object>> myVehicles` to hold this. When I try to put the entries in:

```
List<Bikes> bikes = ...
myVehicles.put("bikes", (List<Object>)bikes);
```

I get an error, "Can't cast from List to List". What do I need to do? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried generics?? Use Generics for this like MyList<T> where everytime T can replace Cars, Bikes, etc... Just the problem is you have to implement it yourself as you will be implementing the List interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your map as:

```
Map<String, List<? extends Object>> myVehicles = 
                                new HashMap<String, List<? extends Object>>();
```

`Map<String, List<Object>>` wouldn't work, because you can't add a `List<Bikes>` where a `List<Object>` is needed, because generic types are *invariant*. A `List<Bikes>` is not a subclass of `List<Object>`, however it can be captured by a `List<? extends Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to declare:

```
Map<String, List<? extends Object>> objectsMap = new HashMap<String, List<? extends Object>>();
```

An example is as follows:

**MapTest class ==>**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class MapTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, List<? extends Object>> objectsMap = new HashMap<String, List<? extends Object>>();

    //Put String List into Map
    objectsMap.put("String", Arrays.asList("Hello","Java"));


    //Put Object List into Map
    objectsMap.put("Object", Arrays.asList(new Object(),new Object()));

    //Put Car List into Map
    objectsMap.put("Car", Arrays.asList(new Car("Band1"),new Car("Band2")));

    //Put Bike List into Map
    objectsMap.put("Bike", Arrays.asList(new Bike("Band1"),new Bike("Band2")));

}
}
```

**Car class ==>**

```
public class Car {

private String band;

public String getBand() {
    return band;
}

public Car(String band) {
    super();
    this.band = band;
}

public void setBand(String band) {
    this.band = band;
}
}
```

**Bike class ==>**

```
public class Bike {

private String band;

public String getBand() {
    return band;
}

public void setBand(String band) {
    this.band = band;
}

public Bike(String band) {
    super();
    this.band = band;
}

}
```